# Создать из текста список списков

Tags: c#, linq

Добрый день! Задача описана в комментарии снизу. Ошибку чеккер на образовательном портале ulearn выдает такую:

> "Error on: a.b!c?d:e;f(g)h;i 
>       0th element (subitems delimited by pipe symbol) should be [], but was [b]"

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace TextAnalysis
    {
    static class SentencesParserTask
    {
        public static readonly string[] StopWords = 
        { "the", "and", "to", "a", "of", "in", 
          "on", "at", "that", "as", "but", "with", 
          "out", "for", "up", "one", "from", "into" };

        /*
        Разбейте файл с текстом на предложения и слова. 
        Считайте, что слова могут состоять только из букв (используйте метод char.IsLetter) или символа апострофа ',
        а предложения разделены одним из следующих символов .!?;:()
        Удалите из файла слова, содержащиеся в массиве StopWords (частые незначащие слова при анализе текстов называют стоп-словами)
        Метод должен возвращать список предложений, где каждое предложение — это список оставшихся слов в нижнем регистре.
        */
        //StopWords.Select(b=>b)
        public static List<List<string>> ParseSentences(string text)
        {           

            var lstStr = text
                .Split('.', '!', '?', ';', ':', '(', ')')
                .Select(a => a.Split(' ',',','\n','\r').Except(StopWords)
                .Where(b => b.Any(c=> char.IsLetter(c)&&char.IsLower(b[0])
                || c=='`'&& char.IsLetter(c) && char.IsLower(b[0])))
                .Select(b => b).ToList())
                .Where(z=> z.Count!=0).Select(z=>z).ToList();

            return new List<List<string>>(lstStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...вы хотите, чтобы вам перевели ошибку на русский язык?

Comment: судя по тексту ошибки, вам нужно оставлять "пустые" предложения. Т.е. вы должны удалить вот это: `.Where(z=> z.Count!=0)`

Comment: к слову, `.Select(z=>z)`, `.Select(b => b)` ничего полезного не делают, удаляйте.

Comment: Я это уже все пробовал. Ошибка не в этом.

Comment: Не может быть, запустите такой код : https://pastebin.com/Gc4aJ7Ec и скриншотом покажите какую (если) получите ошибку.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но чеккер все равно выдал ошибку.
https://pp.userapi.com/c637227/v637227385/3e106/Bj40AmOpQqM.jpg

Comment: не утверждал, что ваш код правильный, но ошибки из заголовка уже нет...сейчас исправим и эту.

Comment: интересно...при запуске код выдает как раз корректный результат - `[c]`, а не `[]`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pNZnyb3d - попробуйте такой код

Comment: эммм... к сожалению тоже нет. Насколько я понимаю там не надо переводить строки в нижний регистр,  а надо выписать слова, которые в нем находятся
https://pp.userapi.com/c637227/v637227385/3e11d/7JFHEhijlKo.jpg

Comment: попробуйте удалить пустые символы еще :     https://pastebin.com/nxdkYb2P

Comment: увы, не работает и это

Comment: новый скриншот покажите

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56719/discussion-between-ev-hyper-and--).